# I am new to python, and realized that i can assign print i.e. an inbuilt function as a variable

Tags: python

I am new to python, and realized that i can assign print i.e. an inbuilt function as a variable, then when i use print('hello world')[this shows the exact error that i faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRIrX.png)
I am familiar to c++ and even in that we were never allowed to use an inbuilt function as a variable name.
those were the fundamental rules for naming a variable
If python.org has issued the new version I'm sure they would have done it for a reason, bbut i want to know how do i access my print statement after assigning a value to it?

Comment: Because built-in names are available in the built-in namespace, which resolves last after the global namespace when you do `some_name`, you can simply do `del print` and it will now resolve to the built-in namespace because `del` will only delete the name from the global (or local) namespace. Note, aside from this special namespace, there is nothing special about the variables that refer to builit-in functions. They are merely names that refer to objects, function objects in this case

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to access your print function unless you do hacky things, which I recommend not to do them in the middle of your code.

Also it is good to know that python (as c++) has scopes for variables, and variables "die" and they are no longer accessible when scope ends. For instance:

```py
def change_print_value():
  print = 3

change_print_value()
print('Print works as expected')
```

It is a good practice to avoid using reserved keywords as variable names. Any IDE has the keywords highlighted, so you can easily realize when you are using a keyword where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

`print` is not part of the reserved keywords list in python. [Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp) a comprehensive list of reserved words.

Functions are [first class objects](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions) in python, so that means they can be treated and manipulated as objects. Since print is a function (and an object), when you call `print = 1`, you reassign the variable `print` to have a value of `1`, so the functionality "disappears".